Window switch -- circuit board contacts
2010 Silverado 1500 extended cab
This is the circuit board of the front left door's window switch.

Why does the left window have two top contacts, but the right only has one?

Every power window switch group that I've ever seen has a more robust switch for the driver's window than for all the others. Some have even had a different style of switch (internally) from all the others.
It's because the driver's window is opened and closed much more often than all the other windows. With a better switch, it has a greater chance of lasting through the warranty period.
In your case, two contacts reduce the current through each switch-half by half, and in the even that one contact wears out completely, the second contact can still do the job.

My age is showing! @Paulster2 gives a better answer for this particular switch, which probably controls a separate switching module rather than carrying the full motor current through those tiny traces. The answer is still valid for older cars.
I started fixing cars before the "module for everything" era, where the window switches were fed by beefy wires and carried the high current that window motors demanded. Switches actually overheated and burned out back then, so using a more robust switch for the driver's window actually paid off. Before electronic tolling and near-universal air conditioning, the driver's window got a lot more use than today.

I'd lay wager it's because of the auto-down feature. If you look at the traces on the board, they are completely different, therefore they have different functions. You'd need to look at the switch lever to see if the two points are contacted at different times in the downstroke to tell for sure. I know on my Silverado (and other GM vehicles I've driven), there is a separate feel for when you get the "window down" function and when you get the "auto window down" function. When you press the switch to just bring the window down a little bit, you'll get a slight click feel, then you press it a bit further and get a 2nd click feel which puts it into auto-down. While I don't know this for a fact, it seems the most logical.
NOTE: I think some call it "express down" and not "auto down". Forgive me if I got that wrong.

Good point! The silicone bubble holding the contact may be a little deeper on the rightward of the two.

Here's a photo of the underside of the switches: https://i.sstatic.net/MWmwW2pB.jpg
